# Logo - small or large wont work

Tags: html, css

http://kvejborg.dk/

Hey guys. I got this page where there a problem with the logo.
When you scroll down so the logo is going to be small and then up again it should be big again. It works fine on safari etc. but not on chrome.
If i right click on it, it is going to be as it need to be. But it need to do it by it self like in safari. Anyone who can tell me what the problem is?

```
<div class="site-logo">
                        <a href="/">
                            <img src="/assets/images/kvejborg-logo.svg" alt="Kvejborg ApS logo">
                        </a>
                    </div>

@media screen and (min-width: 64em)
.site-logo img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].* https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `display: block;` on the logo/img seems to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

have you tried adding the lines of code that will support chrome all major browsers? it should look like this

```
 nav {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url(gradient-slice.png);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top right, #A60000, #FFFFFF);
  background-image: webkit-linear-gradient(top right, #A60000, #FFFFFF);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top right, #A60000, #FFFFFF);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top right, #A60000, #FFFFFF);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top right, #A60000, #FFFFFF);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top right, #A60000, #FFFFFF);
}
```

The -webkit- prefixed property will work in WebKit-based browsers such as Chrome and Safari
The -moz- prefixed property will work in Firefox
The -ms- prefixed property will work in Internet Explorer
The -o- prefixed property will work in Opera